# how to adjust sphinx to index phrases instead of words?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, sphinx

I am using sphinx search engine and php. In my sql table i have something like this`. mother keyboard, india pakistan, stakoverflow god`. Now when i run indexer over it. It is indexing "mother and keyboard " as different words. I want them as a single phrase to be searched. I want this : it will not search if only `mother` comes or only `father` comes. I will search only if `mother keyboard` comes or `keyboard mother` comes.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try to search the exact phrase (which will require that you enable [index_exact_words](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-index-exact-words)).

So, with SphinxQL:

```
SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('="mother keyboard" | ="keyboard mother"');
```

Or, the NEAR operator might help:

```
SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('mother NEAR/1 keyboard');
```

The Sphinx documentation says that NEAR will "match the document when both subexpressions are found within N words of each other, no matter in which order."

You can read more about the extended query syntax [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax)